# c# ignore properties that are null

Tags: c#, json, class, properties

I am doing an C# `Web Api Application` using Framewrok 4.5

The method retrieve a `class` defined like this

```html
public class BGBAResultadoOperacion
    {

        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Severidad { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Descripcion", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to NOT retrieve those Properties that are `NULL`. For that reason I defined Descripcion property like

```
[DataMember(Name = "Descripcion", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
```

As I can not remove a property from a class, I convert the class to Json

```
 var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(response);
```

Where response is an instance of `BGBAResultadoOperacion` class.

But the Json generated say `"Descripcion":"null"`

I can not use `Json.Net` because I am using Framework.4.5.

How can I retrieve data avoiding properties that are null?

Thanks

Comment: "I can not use Json.Net because I am using Framework.4.5." - Json.NET goes down to .NET Framework 2.0; what makes you think you can't use it? Also: does `DataContractJsonSerializer` work here? that *may* do the job? (although it would be a poor cousin to Json.NET)

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147856/generic-null-empty-check-for-each-property-of-a-class

Comment: I traid to add Json.Net via Nuget and says it can not be added becouse i am using framework 4.5, I am not using DataContractJsonSerializer, i have to check out this. thanks

Comment: "Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.1' to ConsoleApp35" - works fine here; are you using an old IDE / tooling?

Comment: OK, i have installed Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.1, I have tried to install Json.Net, that was the error... After I installed it, can you tell me how to follow to avoid null properties? thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the NullValueHandling option when Serializing using Newtonsoft.Json.

[From the documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm):

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Person Partner { get; set; }
    public decimal? Salary { get; set; }
}

Person person = new Person
{
    Name = "Nigal Newborn",
    Age = 1
};

string jsonIncludeNullValues = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.Indented);

Console.WriteLine(jsonIncludeNullValues);
// {
//   "Name": "Nigal Newborn",
//   "Age": 1,
//   "Partner": null,
//   "Salary": null
// }

string jsonIgnoreNullValues = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
});

Console.WriteLine(jsonIgnoreNullValues);
// {
//   "Name": "Nigal Newborn",
//   "Age": 1
// }
```