# C# Web API Method Json Serialized

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, serialization

I am doing a `C# web Api Method` and the Consumer.

Firstly, the method retrieve a class instance and the Consumer call it like this, and parse it to a Class called `R`

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, param).Result;
R value = await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<R>();
```

Now, I need to retrieve from my Api, only the class properties it have data. For that reason it parse the class instance to Json, as i asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54556896/c-sharp-ignore-properties-that-are-null/54557617#54557617), using

```
 string jsonIgnoreNullValues = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                });
```

My web Method definition is simple

```html
   public IHttpActionResult Newemployee([FromBody] RequestManual items)
    {
         ResponseManual response = Service.Newemployee(items.Datos);
         //Before
          return Ok(response);

          //Now
           string jsonIgnoreNullValues = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                });
          return Ok(jsonIgnoreNullValues);
    }

}
```

.NET automatically Serialize to Json in the response, When i Serialize the response to avoid null properties, the respose is getting serialized twice...

How can avoid this, or how can I read this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the formatter at startup. Under the hood Web API is using Json.Net framework, so you will have access to the same serialization settings

*WebApiConfig.cs*

```
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
```

That way you can use the original code as before

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Newemployee([FromBody] RequestManual items) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        var response = Service.Newemployee(items.Datos);
        return Ok(response);
    }
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```